# Error "name 'by' is not defined" using Python Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I keep getting an error as below:

> NameError: name 'By' is not defined

for the code

```
chrome_driver_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
browser.delete_all_cookies()
browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]')))
```

Is my import correct?

Comment: looks like you forgot to import it

Answer (score 107):

You have to import it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 17):

You can import `By` by using:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this line at the top of the code resolved my problem:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```