# What should I import for Selenium's By.XPATH?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The new version of Selenium doesn’t have any old methods, like `.find_element_by_xpath()`, but it introduced the new fabrique method `.find_element(By.XPATH, searched_string)`. Here is the example from [the documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#first-matching-element):

```
vegetable = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "tomatoes")
```

But it does not work, because '**By**' is not defined.  I can't find the example what to import to use this pattern. In Java it is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

And what should I do in Python?

Comment: At "compile" time ([Pylint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint)), the error message may be *"`E0602: Undefined variable 'By' (undefined-variable)`"*.

Comment: Re *"fabrique method"*: Do you mean *[factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)*?

Comment: The canonical question is *[Python Selenium Webdriver (name 'by' not defined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629970/python-selenium-webdriver-name-by-not-defined)*.

Comment: Related (same underlying import problem, despite the title): *[How to get element by tag name or id in Python and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72342517/how-to-get-element-by-tag-name-or-id-in-python-and-selenium)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### selenium.webdriver.common.by

As per the documentation of the [`By`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) implementation:

```
class By(object):
    """
    Set of supported locator strategies.
    """

    ID = "id"
    XPATH = "xpath"
    LINK_TEXT = "link text"
    PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
    NAME = "name"
    TAG_NAME = "tag name"
    CLASS_NAME = "class name"
    CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

So when you use **`By`** you have to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

### Usage

- For *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  vegetable = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "tomatoes")
  ```
- For *XPATH*:

  ```
  vegetable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//element_xpath")
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You have to import the class `By`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```