# Selenium/Pandas Webscrape Not Writing to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I wrote a webscrape on home depot and when I had it just printing the results it seemed to be working then when I tried to store it in a list and write it to a data frame something seemed to go wrong. it does not appear to be storing to the lists nor writing to the data frame. Why would this be? I have included my code below. Thank you!

Error given in console

[image: 1]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv'
path = '/Users/Office/Documents/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)
matches = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-identifier--bd1f5')
prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('price-format__main-price')
brands = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-header__title__brand--bold--4y7oa')
descriptions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-header__title-product--4y7oa')

company = []
prodnum = []
prodprice = []
descs = []


for brand in brands:
    company.append(brand.find_element_by_class_name('product-header__title__brand--bold--4y7oa').text)
   # print(brand.text)
for match in matches:
    prodnum.append(match.find_element_by_class_name('product-identifier--bd1f5').text)
    #print(match.text)
for desc in descriptions:
    descs.append(desc.find_element_by_class_name('product-header__title-product--4y7oa').text)
    #print(desc.text)
for price in prices:
    prodprice.append(price.find_element_by_class_name('price-format__main-price').text)
    #print(price.text)

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame({'company_name': company, 'code': prodnum, 'price': prodprice, 'description': descs})
df.to_csv('HD_test.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Ohh dude which time are you live in lol. Read this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629970/error-name-by-is-not-defined-using-python-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @Elkhan I'm a little bit confused I used that import statement and it did not seem to do anything, its greyed out on line 2 and i am getting the same error message. Sorry if dumb question, I am very new to web scraping lol

Comment: I can't get to access website which you are try to scrape can you enter the site?

Comment: @Elkhan here is the link I am using https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv

Comment: I can not enter this website it says Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv" on this server.
Reference #18.7e861402.1678425243.edd2649 is it same on your pc?

Comment: No it brings up the page for me. I went to home depot >>> tools > Milwaukee

Comment: I think it's relevant to my location.

Comment: But you can use css selectors i think it can be more easier for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two issues with the code that you've provided.
First, you are not waiting for the elements to be present on the page. This causes the script to load up some elements one time, and not the other time. To fix this use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

skus = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-identifier--bd1f5')))
prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'price-format__main-price')))
```

Second, once you've already selected the elements, directly extract the text out in the loop.

```
for sku in skus:
    prod_num.append(sku.text)

for price in prices:
    prod_price.append(price.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine to me when I run it. One issue you may be facing is that the length of `prod_price` and `prod_num` may be different. However, in that case, you should get a separate `ValueError`.

If you don't care about misalignment per se and just want to complete the dataframe, you can use `pd.concat`:

```
df1 = df = pd.DataFrame({'code':prod_num})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'price':prod_price})
new_df = pandas.concat([df, df2], axis = 1)
```

If you do care about alignment, it's probably better to assign the values together by assigning the skus and prices together.